# sort content by tag in Gatsby with Conteful API

Tags: graphql, metadata, gatsby, contentful

In Contentful, I create a content with few media pictures. The pictures have two different tags `boxon` and `attaqueGenetique`. I want to sort the slideshow by using tags I've added for each media, but I don't find the way to do that. There is an example on the website Gatsby, but is not really clear and my try failed to make it mine.

The example from [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#contentful-tags)

```
query FilterByTagsQuery {
  allContentfulNumber(
    sort: { fields: contentful_id }
    filter: {
      metadata: {
        tags: { elemMatch: { contentful_id: { eq: "numberInteger" } } }
      }
    }
  ) {
    nodes {
      title
      integer
    }
  }
}
```

I've supposed I must transpose thise code to mine where
`allContentfulNumber` become `allContentfulDiaporama`, and

```
metadata: {
        tags: { elemMatch: { contentful_id: { eq: "numberInteger" } } }
      }
```

become

```
metadata: {
        tags: { elemMatch: { contentful_id: { eq: "boxon" } } }
      }
```

but when I try to compile the console return
`56:5  error  Field "metadata" is not defined by type "ContentfulDiaporamaFilterInput"  graphql/template-strings`

I don't know where catch metadata from media when it's imported in content... but I'm very beginner with `graphql` and `Contentful`. If there is a solution, that's can make my day happy !!!

Answer (score 0):

`metadata` in Gatsby's example is a GraphQL node valid in their data structure, if yours hasn't it simply don't use it or it will break the code since it's not a valid custom type.

The problem in your query, besides using an invalid field (`metadata`) is that you are using an `elemMatch` filter, comparing`contentful_id` (number) to `boxon` (string), so it will never work in your scenario (it works in Gatsbys' because it's the same type). In your case, you may want to use `in` (for arrays) or `eq` (for single values). Check the available list at: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#filter

As far as I understand your question, it seems that you want to split your `diaporama` data in two different nodes, the ones that contain `boxon` and the ones that contain `attaqueGenetique`. If so, you will need to create different nodes by aliasing them:

```
query FilterByTagsQuery {
  boxon: allContentfulDiaporama(
    sort: { fields: contentful_id }
    filter: {
        metadata: { tags: { in: ["boxon"]  } }
      }
  ) {
    nodes {
      #your data/fields here
    }
  }
  attaqueGenetique: allContentfulDiaporama(
    sort: { fields: contentful_id }
    filter: {
        metadata: { tags: { in: ["attaqueGenetique"]  } }
      }
  ) {
    nodes {
      #your data/fields here
    }
  }
}
```

Test the query in the GraphiQL playground, available at `localhost:8000/___graphql` where it will be much more intuitive for you to add or remove filters and see the available nodes.

The snippet above will generate two different data structures based on the tags aliased. With this: `boxon: allContentfulDiaporama`, you are aliasing the result of `allContentfulDiaporama` in `boxon` so in your page, you will be able to access directly `props.data.boxon` and `props.data.attaqueGenetique` respectively.

Keep in mind that the `sort` filtering method only works on dates or numeric values, in the case of strings, it will sort them alphabetically. So I'm assuming that your data has a `contentful_id` (I'm not sure how it will be helpful sorting by `contentful_id`).

According to this [pull-request](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/34480) the `enableTags` feature was fixed in the cutting-edge release(5 days ago) so try to upgrade your plugin dependency.

It seems to be fixed in, according to this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/34556):

```
gatsby-source-contentful@7.5.0-next.0
```

Or in the next release.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I try tomorrow to translate that in code !!! Is not really easy for me to see all different things who make internet code to understand what do what exactly.

Comment: Sure no worries. If I misunderstood anything on your goal just let me know

Comment: Hmm... i've feeling i cannot acces to the media tagged in my `Conteful`content, the console return ` 58:4  error  Field "tags" is not defined by type "ContentfulDiaporamaFilterInput"  graphql/template-strings`

Comment: The query structure will rely on your data, names and types, that's why I suggested building the query on the GraphiQL playground at `localhost:8000/___graphql`, there, you'll see the fields available and how to filter them. If it's a nested structure you may need to do something `parentField__childField__anotherChildField` instead of `field` when filtering. I cannot know your naming exactly but get the idea.

Comment: Have you set the `enableTags` flag as `true`?

Comment: Yes `enableTag `it was `true`

Comment: If `tags` are not somewhere available in your `allContentfulDiaporama` node is because they are not related/interpoled. Are you using the latest version of the plugin?

Comment: my config `"gatsby-source-contentful": "^5.14.0"` and `"gatsby": "^3.14.2"`