# Sort allContentAsset by tag in Gatsby is it possible?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I try for few days to sort my Asset media by the tag than I added on each Asset in Contentful, but I failed on each try...
See my previous question about that [sort content by tag in Gatsby with Conteful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70744571/sort-content-by-tag-in-gatsby-with-conteful-api/70754005)

So I'm back to a simplest configuration, just sort the raw asset !
What is good sentence to write `sort` and `filter` to catch only the media with tag `artWork`?

Because I try to understand the gatsby example for that... and it's not easy
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#contentful-tags

```
{
  allContentfulAsset() {
    edges {
      node {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Sort allContentAsset by tag in Gatsby is it possible?

Absolutely. You only need to apply one of the multiple GraphQL filters in Gatsby's implementation. For example:

```
{
  allContentfulAsset(
    filter: {
     metadata: { tags: { in: ["art work", "vies paralleles"] } }
    }
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The previous snippet will get `allContentfulAsset` where those `tags` contain `"art work"` and "`vies paralleles"`. Assuming the interpolation between `assets` and `tags`  exists (i.e: `tags` is selectable a field in `assets`). If this interpolation is not present or it's not properly done, `allContentfulAsset` will never have `tags` to filter so your query will break.

Keep in mind that to use tags, you need to set the `enableTags` flag as `true` (set as default as `false`) by:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
  options: {
    spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    enableTags: true,
  },
},
```

According to this [pull-request](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/34480) the `enableTags` feature was fixed in the cutting-edge release(5 days ago) so try to upgrade your plugin dependency.

It should be fixed in (inferred in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/34556)):

```
gatsby-source-contentful@7.5.0-next.0
```

---

*Please provide feedback on previous questions/answers rather than keep opening new ones. Even delete the previous ones or provide feedback about what you've tried...*

Comment: hmm, the `http://localhost:8000/___graphql` give an error message `"Field \"tags\" is not defined by type \"ContentfulAssetFilterInput\"."` maybe like you say in the other comment you ask for my version of Gatsby or Plugin is not good `"gatsby": "^3.14.2"` and `"gatsby-source-contentful": "^5.14.0"`

Comment: Indeed, according to https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/34480 it seems that the `metadata {tags}` is in the cutting-edge version

Comment: ok, i'm on the top of the bug :) You think I need to update Gatsby 3 to Gatsby 4 or juste update the plugin contentful ?

Comment: Gatsby can remain at V3 I guess, unless there's any incompatibility which I haven't spotted in the change log

Comment: I update the plugin `gatsby-source-contentful`to the last version but the problem stay the same `"message": "Field \"tags\" is not defined by type \"ContentfulAssetFilterInput\"."` maybe I must update Gatsby too ! another problem to solve !!!

Comment: Can you get the list of tags at least? https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#list-available-tags (without sorting them)

Comment: Yes, that's work fine `{allContentfulTag {nodes {name}}}` return `"data": {"allContentfulTag": {"nodes": [{"name": "Year: 2017"},{"name": "attaque genetique"},{"name": "art work"},{"name": "boxon"},{"name": "vies paralleles"},{"name": "Year: 2020"}]}},` in the `localhost:800/___graphql` playground

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241196/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-knupel).

Comment: It should be fixed in: gatsby-source-contentful@7.5.0-next.0